# android android.intent.action.call crashing Android app?

Tags: android, android-phone-call

I am trying to make call from my app. But every time it get crashed with no error shown on logcat. I took permission in manifest also check it at runtime.

```
public void call(String number){
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(callIntent);

}
```

Comment: `CALL_PHONE` is runtime permission have you asked it at runtime ? . Put a try catch and debug the Exception .

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure context is not null ? You should do something like this.
Inside your calling activity make these changes

```
private static final int REQUEST_CALL_PHONE_PERMISSION  =  100;


    if( isCallPhonePermissionGranted() ){
        call("<Number>");
    } else {
        call("<Number>");
    }
```

private void requestCallPermission() {
        final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_CALL_PHONE_PERMISSION);
    }

```
   private boolean isCallPhonePermissionGranted() {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) 
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
     }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
           permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
             if (requestCode != REQUEST_CALL_PHONE_PERMISSION) {
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
                grantResults);
               return;
              }

         if (grantResults.length != 0 && grantResults[0] == 
                   PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   call("<Number>");
              return;
         }
   }


      public void call(String number){
         Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
         callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
         callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(callIntent);
      }
```

And finally add this this permission to Android Manifest.xml

```
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the relevant permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

An intent by itself is simply an object that describes something. It doesn't do anything.

```
public void call(String number){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
    context.startActivity(intent);
   }
```

And [How to make call in Android 6.0 and Above](http://How%20to%20make%20call%20in%20android%20marshmallow%206.0%20or%20above)